# sql server XML parameter with namespace attribute

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am passing xml data to a stored procedure. if the xml contains xmlns attributes , it is failing .when i remove xmlns it is working fine. how can i remove xmlns before passing in to stored procedure. i am using sql server 2008 .

Answer (score 2):

Don't try to avoid them - use them!

The easiest way to do this is by using the `WITH XMLNAMESPACES` construct - something like:

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://your.name.space.here/2011/June')
(
   -- your XQuery/XPath code here - it will by default use the namespace given
)
```

You can easily have multiple namespaces, too - and you can give them prefixes as well (and use those in your XPath expressions):

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://your.name.space.here/2011/June' AS ns)
(
   -- your XQuery/XPath code here - it will by default use the namespace given
   ....... xmlcolumn.value('(/ns:root/ns:subelement......)[1]', 'int'). .....
)
```

See the [MSDN docs on Adding XML Namespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177400.aspx) for more details and more explanations